# Kibana shows aggregations on a non-indexed field, is this mapping valid?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am testing a Elasticsearch/Kibana setup to log custom application logs.

I have some fields that I don't want to index or aggregate upon.
I have my mapping as follows

```
        "response_body":{
           "type": "text",
           "index": false
        },
```

I explicitly set index: false, however when using Kibana disicover, by using the left menu I can see some count aggregations on the `response_body`.

I am optimizing for indexing speed, and I don't want to index unnecessary large field, why is Kibana showing this aggregations ?

Is me mapping correct ?